# Are elses really a code smell? Idiomatic way to write Go conditions

Tags: if-statement, go, idioms

Suppose we have a function that takes a pointer to a struct `Thing` and updates its `val` field conditionally.

```
type Thing struct {
   good bool
   val string
}
```

Which of the below approaches is more idiomatic in Go?

this:

```
func setVal(t *Thing) {
    if b.good {
        b.val = "Good"
        return
    }
    b.val = "Meh"
}
```

or this:

```
func setVal(t *Thing) {
   if b.good {
      b.val = "Good"
   } else {
      b.val = "Meh"
   }
}
```

**Why the fuss?**

> *In go if you have an else, that is almost a code smell.
> If you see elses, think of how you can get rid of them. Very often they will simplify your code actually.* -Francesc Campoy

Comment: Feels like your question really is : are else clauses really a code smell

Comment: agreed. let me update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually already answered you question 
This is idiomatic way:

```
func setVal(t *Thing) {
    if b.good {
        b.val = "Good"
        return
    }
    b.val = "Meh"
}
```

because it usually looks simpler.

For example you can take a look to this page [go wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#indent-error-flow)
(**Disclaimer**: On this page described not exactly error handling flow but idea the same, so you can rely on it).

Comment: Yes but who decides which one is good? Do we have some sort of official guideline from the Go team for this? or is this how it's done in the standard libs?

Comment: It is standardized, more info here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#indent-error-flow

Comment: @V.Kovpak the link into CodeReviewComments is about putting normal code path at minimal indentation. I think the question is about elses in general. Also, assuming b.good is normal flow your example does the opposite to what the link says.

Comment: Agree with Andreas but I guess this is the most reasonable way to do it.

Comment: It's not error flow though. The linked article doesn't apply.

Comment: @rustyx but idea the same...

Comment: @rustyx Updated my answer, the goal of answer - share the main idea that there is usually no point to use `else` clause.

Answer (score -1):

As this is not about "error flow" the else per se is not a code smell.

But the code *itself* looks very ungoish: stuff like `setVal` methods smell by themself.

For the logic itself I would probably write:

```
func setVal(t *Thing) {
    b.val = "Meh"
    if b.good {
        b.val = "Good"
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of an extra useless assignment in case b.good is true. So I don't think we should do it like this.

Comment: @JarriAbidi If this is on the hot path of your code you have to redesign anyway. You asked for idiomatic code; it differs from optimized code.

Comment: @JarriAbidi If the extra assignment would be a big enough difference, I would worry about how to remove the branch (`if` statement) much more.